# PHPExcel export xlsx with drawing got bug in width and height

Tags: phpexcel

i'm currently working with a project that need to export data to excel with drawing in it. I'm using PHPExcel 1.7.7 and PHP 5.3.8 on Window XP SP3

After export to xlsx, the content of file look just fine in the normal view, but when i print preview, width and height of the drawing has change

Here is the code snippet i used:

```
   $file_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '\template.xlsx';
    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file_path);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();

    $objDrawing->setPath('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Sunset.jpg');
    $objDrawing->setWidthAndHeight(360, 252);
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('B3');
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save('C:/test.xlsx');
```

Template file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?cq24o5ma20kesgf

Result file: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?x8c50bpdteywx20

Note: In normal mode view, the drawing fit perfectly in the border that i make, but in print preview mode, the drawing has been scaled and if you go to Size and Properties of the drawing, change the option in object positioning at properties tab, the drawing will display properly in print preview mode

Comment: This is a known bug, and hasn't yet been fixed.... and unless someone from the community is willing to look at the problem and fix it (perhaps contributing back to the PHPExcel codebase) then it's fairly low on my priority list

Comment: HI Mark Baker!!!
I already fixed the problem, you can reference to my post from codeplex at http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/394404. Hope it will help you on improving the project
Regard

Comment: thanks for that, will test and include (hopefully before the end of the week) in the 1.7.8 release